# NodeJS copy directories and contents that don't exist already

Tags: node.js

I need a function in NodeJS (or an existent one, although I did't find one) that copies a folder to a diferent location **but** only copies the non existing files in the destination:

Folder to Copy:

```
-- Folder1  
---- Folder1_1  
------- File1_1_1  
---- Folder1_2  
------- File1_2_1
```

Destination Path has:

```
-- Folder1  
---- Folder1_1  
------- File1_1_1
```

So this method should only copy Folder1.2 and it's contents (File1.2.1) since all the other files are present already.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this or if there is a module that has a method that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use [ncp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp) and set the property `options.clobber` to false, then it wont replace any files already existing.

Comment: thank you! i searched that module but didn't notice that option... i'm a nodeJS newbie :p

Comment: sure no problem, im happy i was of help :)